Como enviar mails con oauth2 sin actualizar manualmente el refresh token?
Necesito resolver algo, he creado una api para enviar mails mediante oauth2 y javascript, funciona correctamente, pero cada cierto tiempo , se vence el refreshtoken, y tengo que volver a actualizarlo manualmente desde https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ , existe alguna forma de actualizarlo automaticamente, desde mi api, sin necesidad de hacerlo manualmente?
el trabajo lo tengo realizado en javascript, con nodemailer y oauth2
No encuentro la forma de enviar el mail sin actualizar el refresh token manualmente.
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: accountTransport.auth.user,
            clientId: accountTransport.auth.clientId,
            clientSecret: accountTransport.auth.clientSecret,
            refreshToken: accountTransport.auth.refreshToken,
            accessToken: accessToken,

    },
    } as SendMailOptions); 

lo que pasa,es que al dejar pasar unos días, tengo que actualizar manualmente el refreshToken y quisiera no tener que hacerlo, busco la forma de que se haga automaticamente desde la app

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
